# NFSv4 Server Bind Exports

Tags: linux, nfs, nfs4

I have been trying to set up a NFSv4 Server with one export. In the exported directory, I want mounted file systems via bind and also data stored in the exported directory.

For example:

- /data

  - /bind_mount1
  - /bind_mount2
  - /bind_mount3
  - /dir1
  - /dir2
  - /dir3

The current exports config:

```
/data       *(rw,nohide,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check,insecure_locks,async,insecure)
```

When I mount the export, I can access the directories and files fine but the bind mount are empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"crossmnt" seems to be the additional option you're looking for. (see man exports)

Wrote this once already but it got deleted because "this isn't an answer", but since I'm pretty sure it is, here you go again.  Good luck getting to it in time.

Comment: Added crossmnt option and now works as I want it to. Thank you!